# Unknown Error while installing a root certificate through Setup in Windows

Tags: .net, installation, windows-installer, setup-project, windows-server-2012

I am trying to install a certificate into root from my setup application. The setup application works well if I run from a administrator account, but when I run the setup from a normal user account I get an empty error message (instead of a security warning message) as shown below.

[image]

I looked in the windows event viewer and found nothing relevant to this error. I tried by showing a dummy MessageBox just before adding the certificate to the store and to my amaze I could see the Security Warning window coming properly. if I remove the dummy messagebox code I am again getting the same empty error message.

[image]

Code:

```
private bool AddCertificate(StoreName storeName, X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    if (certificate == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null");

     X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
     StorePermission sp = new StorePermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
     sp.Flags = StorePermissionFlags.OpenStore;
     sp.Assert();
     store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);

     MessageBox.Show("hello");

     store.Add(certificate);
     store.Close();
     return true;
}
```

Investigated the Windows event viewer and could find an event "Application Popup" in system logs getting generated whenever i get this empty error message.

```html
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
+ <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Popup" Guid="{47BFA2B7-BD54-4FAC-B70B-29021084CA8F}" /> 
  <EventID>26</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-05-10T10:02:57.622220900Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>30630</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="1556" ThreadID="1296" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>abcd.efgh.net</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="Caption" /> 
  <Data Name="Message" /> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some extra info might help. If this is a Visual Studio installer project MSI install run for Everyone (InstallAllUsers) then it should elevate before custom actions run (you'd see an elevation prompt) and the CA will run with the system account. In that situation there would be no need for running as administrator, but storing a certificate for the current user (local system account) might not be what you intend. Also, have you tried StoreLocation.LocalMachine?

However, if this is a Just me install then the custom actions won't be elevated so yes, if elevation is required and you'll need to run the Just me install as administrator, and the current user *will* be the installing user. Given these two rather different behaviors it's hard to figure out which you intend, or might cause the problem, and we don't know if you are doing Everyone or Just me.

Also, just as a sanity check, do you have any other custom actions that might have a problem? That's just in case there is another custom action that has errors when not elevated.